# react-native model get pushed when open

Tags: react-native

I am stuck in problem in react-native android platform.

i am implementing react-native-model link is [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-modal)

I have text Input inside modal and when i open the modal and click on text Input at that time keyboard will be popup and at that time modal get pushed up.
is there any solution for that.

i have write in Manifest file

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    ...
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please show your view code

Comment: here are the screenshots i have attached    https://stackoverflow.com/a/47282533/5727262